# Has google chrome updated how select field work?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

If I´m not mistaken, before yesterday, if I used javascript to set a `<select>`'s selected value to an invalid value it would automatically display the first `<option>`'s value.  Now if set it to a non-declared option value, Chrome displays my select option as empty.  This wouldn't be a big deal if I hadn't coded around this action. So I would like to know if anyone else has had this problem or is it just me. (firefox still works)

```js
var select = document.getElementById('test');
select.value = '8';
```

```html
<select id='test'>
  <option value='5'>option5</option>
  <option value='6'>option6</option>
  <option value='7'>option7</option>
</select>
```